# How to get the String value inside my onclick function in android?

Tags: android, string, onclick

```
   final RadioGroup radioGroup1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
              final TextView tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);   
        Button  mSubmitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
        relation.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());
        radioGroup1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        String text1;
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) 
            {
                RadioButton checkedRadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedId);
               text1 = checkedRadioButton.getText().toString();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });


        mSubmitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                 String fName = first_name.getText().toString();
                 String re_lation = (String) relation.getSelectedItem(); 
                 String add_ress = address.getText().toString();
                  }
```

Here inside my Onclick function,i wanna to get the text1 value from onCheckedChanged.how to get the text1 value inside my onclick function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare String text1 as global variable like, Before `onCreate()` method of your activity

```
String text1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {

    }
```

Comment: inside my onclick function,how to get the String text1 value?

Answer (score 0):

Make `String text1;` as a global variable:

```
public class YourActvity extends Actvity {

   String text1;

   public onCreate( //...   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to initialize text1 just below to the class initialization so any method can use this text1 and then set the value in one method and get the value into another method

```
public YourActvity extends Actvity {
String text1;
public method1(
set the value
}

public method1(
get the value
}
```